# Can all mythic spells be cast using wild arcana?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The wording of Wild Arcana (errata notwithstanding) states

> As a swift action, you can expend one use of mythic power to cast any
>   one arcane spell without expending a prepared spell or spell slot. The
>   spell must be on one of your arcane class spell lists and must be of a
>   level that you can cast with that arcane spellcasting class.
>
> You don't need to have the spell prepared, nor does it need to be on
>   your list of spells known. When casting a spell in this way, you treat
>   your caster level as 2 levels higher for the purpose of any effect
>   dependent on level. You can apply any metamagic feats you know to this
>   spell, but its total adjusted level can't be greater than that of the
>   highest-level arcane spell you can cast from that spellcasting class.

Does this mean that since the spell doesn't "need to be on your list of spells known", you could in theory cast any mythic version of a spell at the cost of two mythic points (one for wild arcana and one for the mythic version)?

Comment: If you are willing to burn extra mythic power and spend 30,000 and use up a ring slot, then I have an item for you http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87966/23058

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer:

Unless you have a very generous GM, no.

### Longer Answer:

[Casting a Mythic Spell:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic)

> *If you know the mythic version of a spell*, any time you cast the spell, you may expend one use of mythic power to convert the spell into its mythic version as you cast it.

(emphasis mine)

Since you don't know the mythic version of a spell, that clause doesn't apply. Since that is the only path to Mythic versions of spells, it doesn't look good for using Wild Arcana to cast Mythic versions of spells.

So, how, exactly, do you cast spells with, [Wild Arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths---paizo-inc/archmage#TOC-Wild-Arcana-Su-)?

> The spell must be on one of your arcane class spell lists...

Since the Mythic subsystem doesn't add the Mythic version of spells to any class spell lists, Wild Arcana wouldn't let you cast a Mythic spell that way, either.

And, finally, both the [Mythic Spellcasting ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes#TOC-Mythic-Spellcasting-Ex-) and [Mythic Spell Lore feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/mythic-spell-lore-mythic) exist, which both strongly suggest that the only way to cast the Mythic version of spells is to take the feat and/or ability.

> You can learn a number of mythic spells equal to your tier and can expend mythic power when casting them to enhance the results. To select a mythic spell, you must be able to cast the non-mythic version or have it on your list of spells known.

Comment: I would like to point out Ring of Transcendent Spells http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic-items/other-magic-items which does let you cast mythic versions of spells without knowing the mythic spell. Granted it comes at more of a cost in mythic power and you cant use the augmented versions. But spending 2-5 mythic power to have access to ALL the base mythic versions of spells is sweet. But the ring does cost 30,000.