# Can a mythic spell gained from Mythic Spell Lore be cast using wild arcana?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, mythic-adventures

Let us say I have [Haste](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste) in my Spellbook and took [Mythic Spell Lore](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/mythic-spell-lore-mythic)

> You can learn a number of mythic spells equal to your tier and can
>   expend mythic power when casting them to enhance the results.

and [Wild Arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths---paizo-inc/archmage) when leveling mythic.

> As a swift action, you can expend one use of mythic power to cast any
>   one arcane spell without expending a prepared spell or spell slot. The
>   spell must be on one of your arcane class spell lists and must be of a
>   level that you can cast with that arcane spellcasting class.

Would it be possible to cast Mythic Haste with Wild Arcana? Wild Arcana explicit says that a swift action is necessary. Do I need a second one to use Mythic Spell Lore? The text only says "expend mythic power" but do not state that this is an action.

Comment: The action of Mythic Spell Lore is the same as the action to cast the spell (*when casting them*). Otherwise, since it isn't stated, it would be a standard action, and thus become impossible to use while casting spells.

Comment: The item mentioned in this post might be useful for you http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87966/23058

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm interpreting you correctly,

### No, you cannot use Wild Arcana to gain the benefits of *any* Mythic version of a spell you *could* know, just by having Mythic Spell Lore once.

This is because, unless you select Mythic Haste with Mythic Spell Lore (or similar), it is *not* in your spellbook.

If I misunderstood and you

### Yes you can use the Mythic version if you use Mythic Spell Lore to gain access to the Mythic Haste spell

There is no limit to spending Mythic points in one action and Spell Lore isn't an action, its just adding spells to your book.

### To explain Mythic Spell Lore,

it causes you to *immediately* pick 1 spell/tier from your known spells- you add the Mythic version of them into your known spells. That part is passive. Then, in order to *use* the Mythic version, it costs Mythic Point(s).

You could still cast normal Haste without expending Mythic, or you could Wild Arcana normal Haste for 1 Mythic Point. Using Wild Arcana to cast Mythic Haste spontaneously costs 2 Mythic Points.

Answer (score 3):

If it says "expend mythic power" it only requires you to spend the mythic points from your mythic pool, not use any kind of action.